# How to escape special character in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to use jQuery Validate on a styled Google form. When I try to use the name 'entry.369082719' I get "Unexpected number".

I tried adding double backslash but then I get the "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" message.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#emailSubscription").validate({
ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
    entry\\.369082719: {
      required: true,
      email:true
    }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('#emailSubscription').toggle();
        form.submit();
        $('.hidden-message').show(100);
    }
})
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbOJKv

Comment: try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaOyWj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change
    entry\.369082719:
to
    'entry.369082719':

Comment: Please add explanation. Your answer is currently being voted for deletion

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape the dot using double black slash here , 
you have to use quote around this .
e.g - "entry.369082719"